# Excel report from Pivot table - Issue

Tags: excel, pivot

I have to create a report in excel.I have to use a pivot table as datasource.

For example my pivot table is like below.

Year column is dynamic(count may decrease or increase)

```
Year   Category  Value
-----------------------------
2009   A        58
2012   A        10
2014   B         9
2013   C         7
2014   C         12
2012   C         54
2013   B          8
```

In my excel report I have to show like below.

```
Year  A   B   C
--------------------------
2009 58 0  0
2012 10 0  54
2013 0  8  7
2014 0  9  12
--------------------------
Total 68 17 73
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Flagged, not a programming question. Also, learn to format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use pivot table. this is how i would do it. On the sheet with your raw data, do the following first:

[image]

The formula for column D is

```
=A2&B2
```

and the formula for column E is

```
=SUMIF(D:D,D2,C:C)
```

On a new sheet, manually enter the year for column A. Manually enter the headers "A", "B", "C" for the next 3 columns.

[image]

The formula I have used for column B is `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2&$B$1,Sheet1!D:E,2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(A2&$B$1,Sheet1!D:E,2,0))`
The formula i used for column C is `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2&$C$1,Sheet1!E:F,2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(A2&$C$1,Sheet1!E:F,2,0))`
and the formula i used for column D is `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2&$D$1,Sheet1!D:E,2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(A2&$D$1,Sheet1!D:E,2,0))`

Hope this helps.

Cheers.